# Ethereum, crowdsale returns 0.00 tokens to the wallet

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to set up a basic crowdsale at ethereum testnet and the solidity code I'm using is the basic examples found at

https://ethereum.org/crowdsale#the-code

with steps followed as described in that guide.

The issue first was that the ethereum wallet doesn't accept the code as is to compile due to the first line:
`contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){  } }`

Specifically, its function returns a warning of an unused local variable and won't compile. Is there a way around this other than defining empty variables inside the function?

The second issue is after it's deployed with the modification as mentioned above, it works. But when it sends tokens to the wallet that sent the ether, the amount is always locked at 0.00 tokens.

FULL CODE:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){ receiver; amount; } }

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal; uint public amountRaised; uint public deadline; uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    event GoalReached(address beneficiary, uint amountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    /* data structure to hold information about campaign contributors */

    /*  at initialization, setup the owner */
    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        token addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /* The function without a name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract */
    function () payable {
        if (crowdsaleClosed) throw;
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign */
    function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention the steps leading to this point aka Token creation / shareholder association work with the code as is provided in the guide.

Comment: all of your code snippet should be indented so it is properly displayed by stack overflow UI

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. I solved it by actually defining the `transfer` function as the example from ethereum.org provides an empty one.

I replaced this:

```
contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){  } }
```

By this:

```
contract token {    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

}
```

For your second problem, do you actually have a confirmation that the token created were actually sent? How many ether did you send to the crowd-sale contract? It seems that you are using two decimals for your token and if you defined "Ether cost of each token" of 5 like in the example, you shouldn't send less than 0.05 ether to the crowd-sale contract.

Hope it helps!